# android studio split code over multiple lines

Tags: java, android

In Vb.net, I can split the code using & symbol. Example:

```
 if (a<>b) & _
    (c<>d) then
```

The above code is consider one statement. Is there any similar way that work in Android Studio?

Comment: This is a language question not an IDE question. What language are you using in android studio? Java?

Comment: yes. I using Java language in Android Studio IDE.

Comment: Just press enter, without any **_**. The line is terminated by **;**, not by a newline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java statements can span over multiple lines, no need to specify a line break. (Note this depends on the language, not the IDE).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split across multiple lines no need to terminate the line...